# 2D Vectors push_back

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to push_back numbers into a 2D vector that's composed of 1 row and 1 column.

```
    vector< vector <int>>array;
    array.push_back(vector<int>(3)); 
    array[0].push_back(2);
    cout << array[0][0] << endl;
```

I expected this to return 3, but it returns 0. Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

`vector<int>(3)` creates a [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) containing 3 elements with value `0`.

> 4. Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.

If you want a `vector` containing 1 element with value `3`, you can change to `vector<int>{3}`.

> 10. Constructs the container with the contents of the initializer list init.

e.g.

```
array.push_back(vector<int>{3});
```